# three divs positioning inside table cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

Please help me to align three divs inside table cell as follows:

[image]

Two small divs absolutely positioned at top right and bottom left corners of the table cell. 
One div should be vertically and horizontally centered inside table cell.
Depending on cell height small divs should be able to overlaps centered div.

I was managed to align central div. But i've no idea how to implement small divs.

```
  <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width:inherit; height:inherit;">
      <div style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%;  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: green ">
        first line<br>
        second line
    </div>
</div>
```

Here what i have for the moment:
[http://jsfiddle.net/zm2WW/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/zm2WW/)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. See http://jsfiddle.net/zm2WW/12/ for a demo.

Here is what the middle table cell looks like now:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="containingBlock">
                <span class="topSpan">TopSpan</span>
                <div class="centerCell">text</div>
                <span class="bottomSpan">2</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

And your CSS:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
}

div, span {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.containingBlock {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.centerCell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.topSpan {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.bottomSpan {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0
}​
```

What is going on here is that you have a relative containing block, which provides a backdrop for the absolutely-positioned spans. The div occupies the entire cell, but its contents are centred giving you the same effect.

Comment: Would the downvoter please take a second to offer some constructive criticism? I really don't understand what is wrong with this response.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but i see that in FF bottom span is out of table borders. In chrome and IE it looks ok. And content of the div is not horizontally centered (i've updated your code with my code block for div). http://jsfiddle.net/zm2WW/10/

Comment: Does this do it for you? http://jsfiddle.net/zm2WW/12/ Note that the centre cell is the height of the containing cell, but its contents are nonetheless aligned to the middle. If it is I will update my answer with the code.